# How to build an ActiveMQ client application?

Tags: activemq-classic

I am very new to ActiveMQ, to be exact a first timer. I have build a java application which running an ActiveMQ broker and subscribes to couple of topics. Now I want to build a client application which will publish some messages in some of those topics. But I am not sure how I will get the url of the already running ActiveMQ queue and publish messages from my client application.

Comment: @FlappySocks its a prototype project, so I have to use ActiveMQ as a part of requirement, even for getting experience of ActiveMQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at http://activemq.apache.org/run-broker.html and look at Java samples http://activemq.apache.org/version-5-examples.html

Answer (score 1):

[Java Client For ActiveMQ](http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.com/2013/02/client-for-activemq.html)

- `TopicSubscriber.java` to Subcribe for messages
- `TopicPublisher.java` to to Publish the messages